# Android stored values in string returning null

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store some data retrieved "receiver" and "sender" from my firebase database in a string "room_type_1" and "room_type_2" in my code. The data is being retrieved alright but it isn't being passed to the string. It keeps on returning null. What might be the problem?

```
databaseReference3.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                 receiver = (String) dataSnapshot.child(user_id).child("username").getValue();
                 Log.v("postID2", receiver);

                sender = (String) dataSnapshot.child(user_id).child("username1").getValue();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


         room_type_1 = sender + "_" + receiver;
         room_type_2 = receiver + "_" + sender;


        databaseReference6 = databaseReference5.child(room_type_1);
        databaseReference7 = databaseReference5.child(room_type_2);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = messageArea.getText().toString();

                if (!message.equals("")) {

                    databaseReference6.push().setValue(new Messages(message, sender));
                    databaseReference7.push().setValue(new Messages(message, sender));
                }
            }
        });

        databaseReference6.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                //Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                String message = (String) dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue();
                String userName = (String) dataSnapshot.child("sender").getValue();

                if(userName.equals(sender)){
                    addMessageBox("You:-\n" + message, 1);
                }
                else{
                    addMessageBox(receiver + ":-\n" + message, 2);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code given only **creates** objects with callbacks. The callback methods will be called only after all of these lines are executed, including the assignments. For example, at the moment the line

room_type_1 = sender + "_" + receiver;

executes, neither `sender` nor `receiver` have yet been set to the values from your database.

I suggest you learn more about how callback methods work.

To fix this, just move the assignment into the callback method after you assign `sender` and `receiver`.

Note that variable names ending in numbers indicate that you should use an array or List.